# I want to dynamicly post values in the database from a form. (In PHP and MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, forms, dynamic

I'm a bit stuck on my code right now.

I've dynamicly made a form, like this:

```
$r .= '<textarea name="'.$nid.'-'.$cid.'-'.$i.'-1" class="advice" style="width: 800px;">'.$data->advice.'</textarea><br /></p>';
```

And I want to put whatever the user edits in there, so the value of the text area, in a database with, I think as expected, collumns called nid, cid, scid and aid (where $i, and 1 in this case, are scid and aid).

The post variable, print_r'd btw:

```
Array
(
    [11-1-1-0] => Eengezinswoning (waaronder rijtjeshuis, hoekwoning)
    [11-1-2-0] => Twee-onder-een-kap
    [11-1-3-0] => Vrijstaande woning
    [11-1-4-0] => Appartement (waaronder flat-, boven- of benedenwoning, maisonette) MET LIFT
    [11-1-5-0] => Appartement (waaronder flat-, boven- of benedenwoning, maisonette) ZONDER LIFT
    [11-1-6-0] => Studentenflat met gedeelde keuken en/of badkamer
    [11-1-7-0] => Kamer/studio
    [11-1-8-0] => Seniorenwoning (met of zonder voorzieningen, aanleunwoning)
    [submit] => Opslaan
)
```

What would be the best approach for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know how many textarea there are you can do a foreach

```
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v) {
    pdo::prepare("INSERT INTO tbl (?,?)");
    //> Using $k as 11-1-1-0 and $v as the value
}
```

Comment: But then, how would I see the names of the textarea's, for inserting/updating it into the DB?

Comment: as I said in the comment you have the name of textarea in the `$k` variable

Comment: Great, I didn't know that was possible before. Will accept your answer as soon as possible. Thanks.

Comment: Note that you get each posted element here, so that includes the submit button. Might be wise to filter that out if it's not supposed to go to your DB.

Comment: Right, indeed, thanks for mentioning inquam! I would +1 if I was able to, same for you yes123.